# On form submission I get an error 'Method not allowed' - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have below html and javascript but on form submission I get an error **Method not allowed** though I would like to stay on the same index.html and show the success message.

I have debugged the javascript and it bypasses the **if** condition even I put valid info.

index.html

```
 <form method="post" name="FrmEnquiry" id="FrmEnquiry" onsubmit=" return sendEnquiryform();">
    <input name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">

    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <div class="submit">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

<span id="sucessMessage"> </span>
```

javascript.js

```js
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    $.post('mail.php', '&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + message, function(
        result,
        status,
        xhr
    ) {
        if (status.toLowerCase() == 'error'.toLowerCase()) {
            alert('An Error Occurred..');
        } else {
            alert(result);
            $('#sucessMessage').html(result);
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error); // this shows 'method not allowed' and then i get below alert

        alert('something went wrong. Please try again');
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does backend support POST method?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Whatever absolute URL mail.php resolves to isn't a URL you are allowed to make a POST request to. We can't tell why because we have no idea how that server (assuming it is a server and you're not trying to POST to a `file:` URL) is configured.

Comment: what all i am trying is to get a valid success message on the form after the form is submitted. Trying to avoid it to test on live web host and just trying to do it locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `action` tag to your form.
Like this:

`<form method="post" name="FrmEnquiry" id="FrmEnquiry" onsubmit=" return sendEnquiryform();" action="">`

You can add the value where you want to send the post to.

Also refer to: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: I still get same error:     VM173:1 POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/mail.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(anonymous) @ VM173:1
send @ jquery-3.6.0.js:10109
ajax @ jquery-3.6.0.js:9690
jQuery.<computed> @ jquery-3.6.0.js:9846
sendEnquiryform @ script1.js:59
onsubmit @ index.html:85
script1.js:71 Method Not Allowed